# Wildcard in Excel is selecting full string instead of partial text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I'm having issues with using a wildcard in Excel.

In a column I want to find a value which is called "FFI".
Within this column there is also a number of values called "Office".
I've used two asterisks in my formula to surround "FFI", but it still includes the "Office" values, which contains the same combination of words.

The issue is that the word "Office" contains the words "FFI" within it. The formula is including the cells containing 'Office' when it should only contain "FFI".

The formula works in other cells in which it has to find partial text.

My formula is below:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Pivot_Range[State],{"Active","Proposed"},Pivot_Range[Severity],"*4*",Pivot_Range[Tags],"*"& FFI &"*"))
```

This is the table that I intend to put my data in:

```
| TAG | SEVERITY 1 | SEVERITY 2 | SEVERITY 3 | SEVERITY 4 |
|-----|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| FFI |            |            |            |            |
|     |            |            |            |            |
|     |            |            |            |            |
```

This is the Pivot Table I'm using as my source:

```
| ID   | State    | Severity     | Tags                 |
|------|----------|--------------|----------------------|
| 1234 | Active   | 1 - Critical | CGI                  |
| 2314 | Proposed | 4 - Low      | Model Office Cycle 1 |
| 3547 | Active   | 3 - Medium   | FFI                  |
```

Comment: it's difficult to understand your issue, also the formula seems to be different from the description. Please add some sample data with desired results. (you can format your data e.g. [here](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables))

Comment: The issue is that the word "Office" contains the words 'FFI' within it. The formula is including the cells containing 'Office' when it should only contain 'FFI'.

Comment: The wildcard is a wildcard!! so as long as the text has "ffi"  it will be found, you should consider excluding any texts with "office".... Since "office" has "ffi" in it..... Why not do a temporary replace of the word "office" with "xyxyxy" for example then do the count...

Comment: I was always under the assumption that surrounding the desired value in brackets excluded the rest of the text value. I cannot change the name of the values as it is out of my control, I could manually count it, but my boss wants it all to be automated.

Comment: Can you add some of the data to the question?

Comment: I've just added some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is working perfectly for those interested:

This method is case sensitive for all values as "FFI" is always in capitals.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Pivot_Range[State]={"Active","Proposed"})*(ISNUMBER(FIND("4",Pivot_Range[Severity])))*(ISNUMBER(FIND(FFI,Pivot_Range[Tags]))))
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as an answer. This is allowed and will remove the question from the unsolved section.

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the two `*` that surronds "FFI" should work for you. That means that only exact matches of "FFI" will be counted. By the use of `*` before and after what you want matched, all senetences/words containing "FFI" somewhere will be matched.

Edited formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Pivot_Range[State],{"Active","Proposed"},Pivot_Range[Severity],"*4*",Pivot_Range[Tags],"FFI"))
```

Comment: This returns no values, I tried adding a not equal to operator and this produces the same result.

Comment: @JRiggers for the test data you added, there is no row fulfilling both the criteria of severity of 4 and a tag of FFI which could be why it gives 0. Or the tag with FFI countians a space?

Comment: I threw the test data together quickly, but in the real table the criteria is met. I thought there might be spaces, as I had an issue with that previously. However, the solution I posted as an answer is working.